# Как правильно прописать команду закрытия клавиатуры Бота Вконтакте

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Написал код клавиатуры, все команды работают, но не могу никак прописать команду закрытия. Лазил по интернету ничего дельного не нашел, решил спросить у вас.
Вот код клавиатуры

```py
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

def create_keyboard():
    keyboard = vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboard(one_time=False)

    keyboard.add_button("Команды", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT)
    keyboard.add_button("0", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("Реклама", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("Админы", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
    keyboard.add_button("Аниме", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)

    return keyboard.get_keyboard()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=4.3.%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B):

> Чтобы убрать у пользователя клавиатуру, необходимо отправить сообщение с пустым параметром buttons:
>   `{"buttons":[],"one_time":true}`

Чтобы получить пустую клавиатуру, воспользуйтесь методом `VkKeyboard.get_empty_keyboard()`.

Comment: А как это всё в коде правильно написать?

Comment: Вы же как-то отправляете непустую. Точно также отправляется и пустая.